# Is up down navigation between table cells possible using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

```
<div class="flex-row" *ngFor="let item of model.balanceSheet.intermediateAssets; let i = index;">
      <div class="flex-cell w-2 border border-no-bottom border-no-top border-no-left"> {{item.description | stringShorten:48}} </div>
      <div class="flex-cell border border-no-left calculated" *ngFor="let value of item.wacValues"> {{value.value | wacNumber}} </div>
      <div class="flex-cell border border-no-left" style="padding:1px 2px 1px 1px;">
        <input type="number" [disabled]="syncing" style="border:none;" [(ngModel)]="item.eliminationAdjustment" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="eliminationadjustment + i" (change)="syncIntermediateAssets()" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex-cell border border-no-left calculated"> {{item.consolidatedStatement | wacNumber:true}} </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to perform the cell navigation in angular6 on clicking the up down arrow in keyboard.But the issue is that table is designed using the flex class not by using tr and td.Is it possible to perform the cell navigation using javascript even though each column has no id's to identify?

Comment: AngularJS is wrong tag for this question - it's Angular 2+ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like `colsInRow` variable in your code, you could do something like:

```
columnElement.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
    let parent = event.target.parentNode; // get parent element
    let currentIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, event.target); // get index of current element

    parent.children[currentIndex + colsInRow].focus();
})
```

If you don't, I'd recommend adding it, as it would make this possible and rather easy.

Comment: It might require additional traversing through DOM from `event.target` to get to `div.flex-cell`, and later after selecting given cell, finding input inside. The code I submited is basic idea for this task

Comment: Could you please provide an example?